# Edges of windows on Kubuntu jittering on Thinkpad T420

Tags: kubuntu

When I move a window on Kubuntu on my T420, the windows flicker constantly, although it isn't full on screen tearing. So far, I have tried changing the composition settings, but it isn't working.

GPU: Intel HD Graphics 3000

Comment: Welcome to [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)! What Ubuntu version are you using? [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1200437/edit) your question to add that info there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate on "I have tried changing the composition settings, but it isn't working."